# How to get a video path in java android

Tags: java, android, video-capture

I am working on an App that will upload videos to firebase, the issue is that I followed a certain tutorial to achieve that but the app cannot pick a video from my Android App even after giving all the necessary permissions. The videos file is open correctly but when I click on a particular video for upload, it's not picking the video. I don't know what is the issue. Here is what I did

```
private void openVideo(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,101);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if ((requestCode==101) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data.getData() != null)){
            videoUri = data.getData();

            String path = null;
            Cursor cursor;
            int column_index_data;
            String [] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA};
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
            cursor = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(videoUri,projection,null,null,orderBy);
            column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                path = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                videoTitle = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(path);
            }
            tvVideoSelected.setText(videoTitle);
        }
    }
```